# Change name on child by JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have part of html. How write JQuery code, that replace 'test2' to 'Home'?

```
<div class="customBreadcrumbs">
<span>
    <a href="...">test1</a>
</span>
<span>
    <a href="...">test2</a>//need change here
</span>
<span>
    <a href="...">test1</a>
 </span>
```

I need Jquery like this:

```
$('.customBreadcrumbs ' child child).text("home")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code gets your div's classname and selects its children and selects its second children. Then it updates the link text. More function-based example

```
$('.customBreadcrumbs').children().children().eq(1).text("home");
```

function [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) gets selectors children element(s).
function [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) sets childrens position. (starting at zero)

Shorter version(does the same thing, more based on selectors):

```
$('.customBreadcrumbs span a:eq(1)').text("home");
```

Check JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Shx4H/1/

Answer (score 0):

`$(".customBreadcrumbs span:nth-of-type(2) a").html("home")`

You can see an example at http://jsfiddle.net/2dq9Z/. Basically `:nth-of-type` is a css [pseudo class](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthoftype) that matches elements on the basis of their positions. So we start with the element with the class `customBreadcrumbs`, then find the second `span`, then locate the `a` within that. We then use jQuery's [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method to change the text.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to correct the html tags. You need a closing span, or remove second opening tag for `span`. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/SveFm/